# Define implicit dummy index?

Tags: indexed-variable

I've been looking for a solution to this question for a while. I was wondering if anyone is aware of a way of defining symbolic dummy indices to implement Einstein's convention.

Let me explain with an example. I would like to define, say, an object with one index, defined this way (more or less):

```
T[i_]:=a[i,something]b[something]
```

so that, if I call the object multiple times, the variable "something" is always named in a different way. For example, I would like

```
T[i]T[i]
```

to return something like

```
a[i,symbol1]b[symbol1]a[i,symbol2]b[symbol2]
```

Does anyone know of a way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this should do the trick.

```
Module[{idx = 0},
 T[i_] := (idx += 1; a[i, Subscript[s, idx]] b[Subscript[s, idx]])
 ]
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using the symbolic tensor capabilities of Mathematica. For example, define `a` to be a matrix and `b` to be a vector:

```
$Assumptions = a ∈ Matrices[{d,d}] && b ∈ Vectors[d];
```

Then `T` is defined as:

```
T = TensorContract[TensorProduct[a,b],{{2,3}}];
```

and `T.T` is:

```
res = TensorContract[TensorProduct[T, T], {{1, 2}}]
```

> TensorContract[TensorProduct[TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, b], {{2, 3}}], TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, b], {{2, 3}}]],
> {{1, 2}}]

This can be simplified with [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce):

```
TensorReduce[res]
```

> TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, a, b, b], {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}}]

For you particular example, it is possible to use the [`ResourceFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["ToTensor"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ToTensor) and ["FromTensor"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FromTensor) and avoid [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract)/[`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct):

```
T = a . b;
TensorReduce[T . T //ResourceFunction["ToTensor"]] //ResourceFunction["FromTensor"]
```

> b.Transpose[a].a.b